# Wordpress category else-condition not working

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to setup a way to display related posts by category and exclude current one, but when a category has only one post, my current code to display anything else, is not working.

This is the code that I have so far. Any ideas why?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title() ?></h1> 

<?php the_content();?>

<?php $current_post_id = get_the_ID(); $post_cats = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID(), NULL );  ?> 
<?php query_posts('showposts=8&orderby=desc&cat='.implode(',',$post_cats)); if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php $i=0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if($current_post_id==get_the_ID()) continue; $i++; ?>

<span class="related-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php short_title('...', 43); ?></a></span>

<?php endwhile;?>

<?php else : ?>
<p>Sorry! There is no more related posts in this category.</p>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>           
<?php endwhile;endif ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php get_template_part('includes/loop-tips');?>
```

Comment: Not sure the cause of the problem, though using `query_posts` for anything other than replacing the main loop is discouraged (see [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)); apparently it has all sorts of side-effects.  Try `get_posts` or `WP_Query` instead.  You might be able to avoid the post id check if you exclude it with the `WP_Query` parameter `post__not_in`.

Comment: @Hobo Thanks for pointing me out. Although I didn't make this code work, I have followed your recommendation about query_posts.